# Availability of SOME/IP Fire and Forget mechanism implementation steps or code

Tags: network-programming, communication, virtual-ethernet

I was trying to implement communication between two devices using vSOMEIP repo by fire and forget mechanism without service discovery. But, there is very less documentation and technically no code implementation available.

Could someone please help with the code implementation for vSOMEIP with fire and forget mechanism without service discovery between two devices with two different IP address.

My use case is like I need to send data using SOME/IP protocol such that no handshaking takes place and there is no acknowledgement sent via client to server, but only data should be sent continuously from server to client using the unicast address.

I tried using the static routing concept by adding unicast address under the Services block in the configuration file. But, that doesn't work.

Issue IDs related to it -

1. https://github.com/COVESA/vsomeip/issues/544
2. https://github.com/COVESA/vsomeip/issues/547